# Actionscript 3 - Assign variables on file load

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I am making an audio player app that collects variables based on javascript running on the page.  By default it loads 2 mp3s, but I need to be able to re-assign the mp3s that it loads based on different javascript clicks.

I think what I want to do is assign the default 2 songs to variables on file load.  Then call a function that re-assigns those variables to the javascript variables passed in.

My question is - how do I create a function that only runs on initial load?  I assume I could then use javascript to call a different AS3 function to stop the player, re-assign the variables, load the file, and then start it again.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some variables available on file load, the easiest way would be to pass them as [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html).